# Как сохранить и прочитать ключ в бинарном виде? (CNG)

Tags: c++

Я сгенерировал симметричный ключ с помощью CNG, и для его  дальнейшего использования, записываю его файл в бинарном виде (writing_in_file). Но при попытке считать, ключ не совпадает.

Я понимаю что проблема связана с тем, как я записываю (writing_in_file) и считываю ключ (read_from_file), но где именно я ошибся я не пойму.

Функции с которыми у меня проблеммы:
Запись в файл:

```
void writing_in_file(char* file_name, BYTE* data) {
    ofstream out(file_name , std::ifstream::binary | std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
    if (out.is_open()) {
        out.write((char*)data, 16);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Чтение из файла:

```
void read_from_file(char* file_name, BYTE* datae) {
    std::ifstream in(file_name, std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::in);
    if (in.is_open()) {
        const int file_length = in.tellg();
        char* data = new char[file_length];
        in.seekg(in.beg);
        in.read(data, file_length);

        BYTE pbKeyObject[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            pbKeyObject[i] = (unsigned char)data[i];
        }

        std::cout << "From file:" << endl;
        PrintBytes(pbKeyObject, 16); // печатаю ключ, который считал из файла
        std::cout << endl;
        in.close();
    }

}
```

Остально код работает коректно. Суть проблеммы в том, что я не знаю, как записать и считать из бинарного файла тип BYTE.

Основной код программы:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt")

#define NT_SUCCESS(Status)          (((NTSTATUS)(Status)) >= 0)

#define STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL         ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000001L)

void PrintBytes(IN BYTE* pbPrintData, IN DWORD cbDataLen) { // Для печати (Взято из документации)
    DWORD dwCount = 0;

    for (dwCount = 0; dwCount < cbDataLen; dwCount++)
    {
        printf("0x%02x, ", pbPrintData[dwCount]);

        if (0 == (dwCount + 1) % 10) putchar('\n');
    }

}

static NTSTATUS gen_random(BYTE* buf, ULONG buf_len) { // создание ключа (Он генерируется и записывается в pbKeyObject)

    BYTE rgbAES128Key[16]; //ключ, из которого создается ключевой объект
    PBYTE pbKeyObject = nullptr;
    DWORD cbKeyObject = 0; // Адрес буфера, который получает значение свойства.
    DWORD cbData = 0; // Размер буфера cbKeyObject
    DWORD cbBlockLen = 0; // Адрес буфера, который получает значение свойства
    PBYTE pbIV = nullptr; // адре пространства для вектора инициализации
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = nullptr; // дескриптор ключа
    BYTE rgbIV[16];// вектор инициализации
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlg = nullptr;
    NTSTATUS status = NTE_FAIL;
    do {
        status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlg, BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM, nullptr, 0);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            return status;
        }


        status = BCryptGenRandom(BCRYPT_RNG_ALG_HANDLE, (PUCHAR)rgbAES128Key, 16, 0);
       if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            return status;
       }

        status = BCryptGenRandom(BCRYPT_RNG_ALG_HANDLE, (PUCHAR)rgbIV, 16, 0);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            return status;
        }

        status = BCryptGetProperty(
            hAlg,
            BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
            (PBYTE)&cbKeyObject,
            sizeof(cbKeyObject),
            &cbData,
            0);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            return status;
        }

        pbKeyObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbKeyObject);
        if (NULL == pbKeyObject) {
            std::wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
            return ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }

        status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbBlockLen, sizeof(DWORD), &cbData, 0);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            return status;
        }

        pbKeyObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbKeyObject);
        if (NULL == pbKeyObject)
        {
            std::wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
            return ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }

        status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_BLOCK_LENGTH, (PBYTE)&cbBlockLen, sizeof(DWORD), &cbData, 0);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            return status;
        }

        if (cbBlockLen > sizeof(rgbIV))
        {
            std::wprintf(L"**** block length is longer than the provided IV length\n");
            return ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }

        pbIV = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbBlockLen);
        if (NULL == pbIV)
        {
            std::wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
            return ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }

        std::memcpy(pbIV, rgbIV, cbBlockLen);

        status = BCryptSetProperty(hAlg, BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE, (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC,
            sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_CBC), 0);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            return status;
        }

        status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAlg, &hKey, pbKeyObject, cbKeyObject, (PBYTE)rgbAES128Key,
            sizeof(rgbAES128Key), 0);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            return status;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            buf[i] = (BYTE)pbKeyObject[i];
        }

    } while (0);
    if (hAlg) {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlg, 0);
    }
    return status;
}

void writing_in_file(char* file_name, BYTE* data) {
    ofstream out(file_name , std::ifstream::binary | std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
    if (out.is_open()) {
        out.write((char*)data, 16);
        out.close();
    }
}

void read_from_file(char* file_name, BYTE* datae) {
    std::ifstream in(file_name, std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::in);
    if (in.is_open()) {
        const int file_length = in.tellg();
        char* data = new char[file_length];
        in.seekg(in.beg);
        in.read(data, file_length);

        BYTE pbKeyObject[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            pbKeyObject[i] = (unsigned char)data[i];
        }

        std::cout << "From file:" << endl;
        PrintBytes(pbKeyObject, 16); // печатаю ключ, который считал из файла
        std::cout << endl;
        in.close();
    }

   
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

    int index_key = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-key") == 0) {
            index_key = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    PBYTE pbKeyObject[16];
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = gen_random((BYTE*)pbKeyObject, 16))) {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by gen_random\n", status);
    }

    std::cout << "Key:" << endl;
    PrintBytes((BYTE*)pbKeyObject, 16); // печатаю сгенерированный ключ
    std::cout << endl;

    writing_in_file(argv[index_key], (BYTE*)pbKeyObject);
    PBYTE pbKeyObjects[16];
    read_from_file(argv[index_key], (BYTE*)pbKeyObjects);

    return 0;
}
```

**Парамтры для компиляции visual studio: -key key.bin**

Comment: Если файл открывается в бинарном режиме, то следует использовать функции `read` / `write`.

Comment: @user7860670, я изменил, но результат примерно тот же .

Comment: Вот вы пишите *"Но при попытке считать, я ключ не совпадает."*, однако в коде таких проверок нет. Зато есть тонны кода, явно не относящегося к указанной проблеме. Так что я проголосовал за закрытие вопроса по причине того, что в вопросе не приведен [mcve].

Comment: Я указал, что функция gen_random создает сам ключ, который имеет тип PBYTE, и на неё не стоит обращать внимание. Проблема возникает при чтении и записи. Я бы очень хотел убрать лишний код, но если я его уберу, то есть вероятность, что я введу некорректный ключ. И тогда весь смысл вопроса теряется.

Comment: В проблеме про чтение ключа из файла должен быть только файл с эталонными данными и собственно код чтения и сравнения ключа с эталонными данными. Как вы там его генерируете и для чего потом используете к проблеме чтения не имеет никакого отношения. Проблемы надо локализовывать, а не вываливать сюда весь свой код, никому не охота копаться в этой каше.

Comment: размер файла неправильно считаете. [How can I get a file's size in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840148/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c)

Comment: В write_to_file поменяйте std::ifstream::binary на std::ofstream::binary и добавьте вывод данных до записи, и после чтения. Остальной код можно убрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @AlexGlebe. Как оказалось, вся проблема была связана с тем, как я получал размер файла для функции *read_from_file*. В итоге вместо

```
const int file_length = in.tellg();
```

Я получаю размер следующим образом:

```
const long file_length = GetFileSize(file_name);
```

Используя функцию:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

long GetFileSize(std::string filename)
{
    struct stat stat_buf;
    int rc = stat(filename.c_str(), &stat_buf);
    return rc == 0 ? stat_buf.st_size : -1;
}
```